# AdBlock блокирует GTM - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension, google-tag-manager

Есть проблема с блокировкой Google Tag Manager плагинами adguard и adblock plus в Chrome на сайте https://sub.example.com

На сабдомене https://sub.example.com отдельная инсталляция Word Press,  точно такая-же как и на https://example.com

На обоих сайтах одинаково установлен один и тот же контейнер tagmanger.

Только вот на сайте https://example.com  проблем нет, а на сабдомене почему то есть. 
Почему Adblock блокирует GTM на сабдомене а на основном нет?
Конечно, если добавить фильтр в AdBlock, то всё  будет нормально, но это решит проблему только на моем компьютере.

Подскажите в чем проблема, спасибо

Comment: В сработавшие правила посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Адблок блокирует всё что шлет запросы с/на сторонние ресурсы, поэтому скорее всего и на поддомене и на основном домене он заблокирован.
Для обхода блокировки GTM необходимо загружать не через стандартный домен googletagmanager.com, а через свой поддомен.
Вот тут подробно описано как это можно сделать: https://stape.io/avoiding-google-tag-manager-blocking-by-adblockers/

В кратце: вы создаете сервер контейнер GTM, на него направляете свой любой поддомен и в коде тэга GTM заменяет ссылку googletagmanager.com на свою, например gtm.example.com.
Таким образом все скрипты GTM грузятся с вашего поддомена и блокировками воспринимаются не как сторонние скрипты, а как скрипты сайта.